# Forced oath to make someone do something

Tags: oaths

I have a friend whose parents made a kosom(oath) in the name of Allah (SWT) that she won’t be continuing relationship with a guy she likes because they think he is not good looking or rich enough. But my friend tried to convince her parents several time so that they accept it and let her marry the person she likes. They didn’t listen and now they are forcing her by making this oath. The question is does this oath count? If she breaks tha oath what is the punishment? Is this type of forced oath (against the girl’s will) even valid?

Comment: You should be more worried about your friend being in a relationship with a non-Mahram

Comment: That’s ofcourse a point. But according to the oath she won’t even try to convince her parents or try to do anything regarding this.